# How to give autonumber to item list but every day start from 1

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, column, calculated-column

How to give autonumber to item list but every day start from 1?

I would like to achieve that every day counter(or with out counter) of item list will be reset and first item in day will give 1 and every day the same?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the Enterprise license? If so, this can easily be done if you edit the list form with Infopath and set a few rules to populate the field.

If you want to do this with SPD workflows only, it will be a bit more complicated.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have Enterprise license, I am wondering if it is possible to do by Calculated Field?

Comment: I have done it by two lists, first main list with workflow and second with caculated column and two workflow and it works perfect. First list get auto number form second I use this way: http://gihanmaduranga.blogspot.com/2012/09/create-auto-increment-number-column-in.html and I added loop which reset first numer to 0 every day at midnight. If someone want detalis please write to me...